# Chrome Dev Tools: Inspector showing wrong element size?

Tags: html, google-chrome-devtools

[image]

In the screenshot above, you can see the element's width is 795.594. `width()` and the chrome dev tool inspector show the same value.

In the screenshot below, I have added `padding-right:18px` to the current element, you can see that dev tool shows the width is 798.33, while `width()` shows 780. I understand that the width shown by Dev tool include padding's width while `width()` doesn't, but where does this number 798.33 come from?

[image]

The HTML is like

//the green block
    ......
     // the small space to the left
         something something ....    //adding padding-right:18px will raise the problem
         SOMETING 
    
    ......

Answer (score 0):

See the CSS part when u inspect element

- is CSS showing different value ?